# Errno 20: Not a directory when saving into zip file

Tags: python, matplotlib, directory, save, zip

When I try to save a pyplot figure as a jpg, I keep getting a directory error saying that the given file name is not a directory. I am working in Colab. I have a numpy array called z_img and have opened a zip file.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from zipfile import ZipFile

zipObj = ZipFile('slices.zip', 'w') # opening zip file
plt.imshow(z_img, cmap='binary')
```

The plotting works fine. I did a test of saving the image into Colab's regular memory like so:

`plt.savefig(str(ii)+'um_slice.jpg')`

And this works perfectly, except I am intending to use this code in a for loop. ii is an index to differentiate between each image, and several hundred images would be created so I want them going in the zipfile. Now when I try adding the path to the zipfile:

`plt.savefig('/content/slices.zip/'+str(ii)+'um_slice.jpg')`

I get: **NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/content/slices.zip/150500um_slice.jpg'**

I assume it's because the {}.jpg string is a filename, and not a directory per se. But I am quite new to Python, and don't know how to get the plot into the zip file. That's all I want. Would love any advice!

Comment: save into `io.BytesIO` object then append the buffer into zip file

Comment: The file system doesn't know that you've got a zip object with that name. Instead, create a file object on the zip object and use it. I think this will work: `with zipobj.open(str(ii)+'um_slice.jpg', 'w') as fp: plt.savefig(fp)`. If you write a running example (it could be a fake plot - all you care about is the savefig) then I could test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs, [matplotlib.pyplot.savefig](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) accepts a binary file-like object. [ZipFile.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) creates binary file like objects. These two have to get todgether!

```
with zipobj.open(str(ii)+'um_slice.jpg', 'w') as fp: 
    plt.savefig(fp)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works :)

Answer (score 1):

First off, for anything that's not photographic content (ie. nice and soft), JPEG is the wrong format. You'll have a better time using a different file format. PNG is nice for pixels, SVG for vector graphics (in case you embed this in a website later!), PDF for vector, too.

The error message is quite on point: you cannot just save to a zip file as if it was a directory.

Multiple ways around:

- use the `tempfile` module's `mkdtemp` to make a temporary directory, save into that, and zip the result
- save not into a filename, but into a buffer (BytesIO I guess) and append that to the compressed stream (I'm not too familiar with `ZipFile`)
- use PDF as output and simply generate a [multipage PDF](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/multipage_pdf.html); it's not hard, and probably much nicer in the long term. You can still convert that vector graphic result to PNG (or any other pixel format9 as desired, but for the time being, it's space efficient, arbitrarily scaleable and keeps all your pages in one place. It's easy to import selected pages into LaTeX (matter of fact, `\includegraphics` does it directly) or into websites (pdf.js).